# Order of a group of matrices

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

I have to calculate the order of the group $G=\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{Z}_m)$ with $m=p^k$ for $p$ prime and $k\in \mathbb{N}$.

So I was thinking on the homomorphism $\det: G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$, and the kernel of $\det$ I think should be $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and then the order of the group $G$ will be $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} ((p^k-1)-(k-1))$. Am I on the right direction or not?

Comment: Note that $A\in GL(n,\mathbb{Z}/m)$ iff $\det(A)$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/m$.

Comment: I fixed some of your grammar and changed a couple of $\LaTeX$-ey things. However, do you mean that "...the kernel of $\det$ should *be* $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$", or "...the kernel of $\det$ should *have order* $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$"? That said, your approach should work in theory, but I see no obvious way to conclude that the kernel of the determinant has that order...(You could just count the matrices with non-zero determinant...no?)

Comment: Thanks for the edits, i am on my cell, and i am not used to write latex on that media, yes i yet have to probe that the kernel has that order... i think yes, but i am still trying to prove it